# Closing keyboeard, submit button

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I need to close the keyboard when a user presses a submit button so the data behind the keyboard can be seen. Here is how I have the button wired, but its not working.

Any ideas?

```
        Button clearbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Submitbutton);
        Submitbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                {

                    //...etc...
                    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);


                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (also, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932692/hide-keyboard-on-click)).

```
Button clearbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Submitbutton);
Submitbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v){
        ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(EditTextAirportCode.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }
```